# PHP foreach with a condition only extract first value

Tags: php, if-statement, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array as

```
$apps = array(
array(
    'id' => '2',
    'name' => 'Popcorn'
),
array(
    'id' => '1',
    'name' => 'EveryCord'
),
array(
    'id' => '2',
    'name' => 'AirShou'
),
```

Here I want to print names where `id="2"`. So I tried it with following code.

```
foreach ( $apps as $var ) if ($var['id'] == "2") {
 echo $var['name']
}
```

The problem is that it only print first result of the array as

```
"Popcorn".
```

But I want to extract all result which are

```
"Popcorn and Airshou"
```

How can I fix this. Can someone help me !

Comment: I've just checked your own example. Your code is missing a semicolon after `echo $var['name']`. When the typo is corrected, your issue cannot be reproduced.

Comment: your code is working fine... it was typo error as Quasimodo mentioned...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this;

```
$apps = [
    ['name' => 'Fish', 'id' => 2],
    ['name' => 'Chips', 'id' => 1],
    ['name' => 'Sticks', 'id' => 2],
];

$using = [];
foreach ( $apps as $var ) {
    if ($var['id'] == "2") {
        $using[] = $var['name'];
    }
}

echo implode(" and ", $using);
```

RESULT: 
[image: Code result]

Comment: Same issue. Nothing change of the result

Comment: Can't be because tested it.  Check your array for the id's.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the array on the item `id` and then retrieve the column `name`:

```
array_column(array_filter($apps, function($v){return '2' === $v['id'];}), 'name')
```

result:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(7) "Popcorn"
  [1] =>
  string(7) "AirShou"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sample array.

And append the name to it, if it is `id=2`

Code:

```
$apps = [
['id' => '2', 'name' => 'Popcorn'],
['id' => '1', 'name' => 'EveryCord'],
['id' => '2', 'name' => 'AirShou']
];
$names = [];
if (! empty($apps)) {
    foreach ($apps as $elem) {
        if ($elem['id'] == 2) {
            $names[] = $elem['name'];
        }
    }
}
$finalName = ! empty($names) ? implode(' and ', $names) : '';
echo '<pre>';print_r($finalName);echo '</pre>';
// Output: Popcorn and AirShou
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop by this code, and you will got both names,

```
foreach ( $apps as $var ){
    if ($var['id'] == "2") {
        echo $var['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: then you should check your array, nothing is complex in it, just a loop and an if condition,

Answer (score 0):

Just grab names in array then implode it like this:

```
$temp = array();
foreach ( $apps as $var ) if ($var['id'] == "2") {
 $temp[] = $var['name']
}
echo implode(' and ', $temp);
```

Comment: Same issue. Nothing change